# Does hero casting rate increase in-combat summoning/repairing?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I started playing Dungeon Defenders recently having a lot of fun with it, still trying to figure out what stats affect what. Does increasing my hero cast rate increase how fast I can summon/repair towers during the combat phase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it increases your summoning and repairing speed in combat, but you get an extra modifier when in build phase.

From the Dungeon defender wiki about [hero casting rate](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_Casting_Rate):

> The Hero Casting Rate stat determines how fast the hero will heal
>   itself, cast, upgrade and repair defenses.
>
> - Having a Hero Casting Rate stat < 0 (negative) will be the same as if it was zero.
> - In the Build Phase of a wave, a hero's casting rate is always significantly faster than in the Combat Phase, while still determined by Hero Casting Rate stat.

Like most other stats it has diminishing return, graph from the [Stat Progression Graph wiki page](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Stat_Progression_Graphs#Hero_Casting_Speed):
[image]

While leveling it could be a good idea to place some points in hero casting speed, but once you get a good godly set or better gear you should get plenty of points in hero casting speed from items so you can place your points in other stats.

Comment: To be honest, casting speed also affects healing (and Hero abilities), so it would be more useful than anything else for a character doing Assault runs (after they've already maxed H.Attack and H.Health, of course).